# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in laravel

Tags: laravel

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in laravel while am getting products from whmcs using api
This is my json data from whmcs api

```
"products": {
"product": [
{
"pid": "1",
"gid": "1",
"type": "hostingaccount",
"name": "super lite",
"description": "1 website",
"module": "cpanel",
"paytype": "recurring",
"pricing": {
  "INR": {
    "prefix": "\u20b9",
    "suffix": "INR",
    "msetupfee": "0.00",
    "qsetupfee": "0.00",
    "ssetupfee": "0.00",
    "asetupfee": "0.00",
    "bsetupfee": "0.00",
    "tsetupfee": "0.00",
    "monthly": "-1.00",
    "quarterly": "-1.00",
    "semiannually": "-1.00",
    "annually": "1668.00",
    "biennially": "3096.00",
    "triennially": "3924.00"
  }
```

This is my controller code

```
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
public function show(){

    $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
        'pid',
        'name',
        'price',
        'description'


    ]);

    return view('main.SME_Hosting',['products'=>$products]);
   }
    }
```

This is my view code

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
          {{$product->name}}              

@endforeach
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('SME_Hosting','GetProductController@show');
```

Comment: show us what `dd($products)` gives

Comment: Change this: `{{$product->name}}` to this: `{{$product['name']}}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply admcfajn but i got an error like this

Illegal string offset 'name'

can you please give any solution

Comment: @john before your return view() try dd($products), than you will see what are the data you receive from api, also what kind of array it is, is it json format? etc etc. Check my answer, hope it will cover your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what's the response you received from your API. BTW use compact to pass data, it's much more cleaner.

```
class GetProductController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){

    $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
        'pid',
        'name',
        'price',
        'description'
    ]);

    return view('main.SME_Hosting',compact('products'));
   }
 }
```

So, to display your result data use the code below. choose either one based on your data type.

**Object Array**

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
          {{$product->name}}              

@endforeach
```

**normal Array**

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
     {{$product['name']}}        
@endforeach
```

If you happen to receive json data from API. Convert the data into array.
class

```
GetProductController extends Controller
    {
        public function show(){

        $products = Whmcs::GetProducts([
            'pid',
            'name',
            'price',
            'description'
        ]);

        $products = json_decode($products, true); // This will make it Object array.

        return view('main.SME_Hosting',compact('products'));
       }
     }
```

It is always good to use **dd($products)** to learn what kind of data you receive from API.

Comment: i got an error trying to get property non object "name".my json data

"products": {
"product": [
  {
    "pid": "1",
    "gid": "1",
    "type": "hostingaccount",
    "name": "super lite",
    "description": "1 website",
    "module": "cpanel",
    "paytype": "recurring",
    "pricing": {
      "INR": {
        "prefix": "\u20b9",
        "suffix": "INR",
         "monthly": "-1.00",
        "quarterly": "-1.00",
        "semiannually": "-1.00",
        "annually": "1668.00",
        "biennially": "3096.00",
        "triennially": "3924.00"
      }

Comment: if you get json data from API, try in your controller $products = json_decode($products, true). in your view try : {{$product->product->name}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to just change this `{{$product->name}}` to `{{$product['name']}}`.
Its because of your $products in an array so in order to access any element from the array you need '[]'.

Comment: I got  an error in my controller code. json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @john this error is generated bcoz json_decode() is expecting to decode string and you are providing it as an array. can you please show your json_decode() controller code for further clarification??

Answer (score 0):

Please check your $products if empty or not like below way. You should try below solution.

```
@if(!empty($products)
   @foreach ($products as $product)
      @if(isset($product->name) && $product->name =="")
           {{$product->name}}
       @else
         No record   
      @endif              

   @endforeach
@else
    No record Found....
@endif
```

Comment: If it's an array and it's empty, it won't get to the `{{ $product->name }}` line anyway. So that won't help

Comment: if your array is empty then you never print the {{ $product->name }} , But if {{ $product->name }}  only empty then you are checking with condition, please check my edited answer.